# Response failure REST api in swift

Tags: swift, rest

I am sending a POST request with headers, both request and response are in base64 format. The response is showing `{"status":"failure","data":null}` See the below code where am going wrong. May be because of header fields are not concat. And it is showing this error also `Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0`

```
 loginrequestData.setValue(userNameTxtFld.text, forKey: "loginname")
            loginrequestData.setValue(passwordTxtFld.text, forKey: "password")
            loginrequestData.setValue(uuid, forKey: "mac_id")

            let jsonString = JSONStringify(loginrequestData,prettyPrinted: true)
            print("JsonString", jsonString)
            let loginData: NSData = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            base64LoginString = loginData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())
            //print("Postman", base64LoginString)

        let url = NSURL(string: "url")

        //create request object
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:url!)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("987654321", forHTTPHeaderField: "X-API-KEY")
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

        // insert json data to the request

        let loginArguments = "data=\(base64LoginString)"
        print("loginArguments", loginArguments)

        request.HTTPBody = loginArguments.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        let httpCallTask = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request){
            data, response, error in
            if error != nil {
                print("error-\(error)")
            }
            print(NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))

            let loginResponse = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            print("loginResponse",loginResponse)

           // print("response",response)

//       let decodedData = NSData(base64EncodedString: loginResponse, options:NSDataBase64DecodingOptions.fromRaw(0)!)
//        let decodedString = NSString(data: decodedData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
//         println(decodedString)

            do{
                //initialize json object
                let jsonToken = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
                print("Hello")
                if let jsonObject : AnyObject = jsonToken {

                    print (jsonObject)

                    //                    //extract data from json object
                    //                    let token = jsonObject["token"]
                    //
                    //                    //store token to user defaults
                    //                    let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                    //                    defaults.setObject(token, forKey: "token")


                }
            }catch{
                print("JSONError:\(error)")
            }

        }
        httpCallTask.resume()
```

Help me out

Comment: Probably not related but don't send pretty printed strings to the server. It doesn't care about aesthetics.

Comment: I don't think debugging chunks of code is not a good use of the site. Please boil it down to an MWE.